# Add 1-2 seconds of silence to a .mp3 file (prefer using VLC)

Tags: mp3

I have 2 to 6 .mp3 files every day (I'm on Windows 10)
I'd like to use VLC to batch add say 2 seconds of silence and the end of each .mp3 file.
Prefer to use command line if anyone could help, Thanks!!
If not possible with VLC, could you also recommend other ways please?